# Creating reference of Interface and assigning it the implementing object considered a clean design decision

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

I have a base class called Tiger

```
class Tiger implements Attack{
@Override
public void pounce(int intensity){
}
@Override
public void threatLevel(int level){
}
```

}

Attack interface:

```
Interface Attack{
void pounce(int intensity);
void threatLevel(int level);
 }
```

Another subclass SiberianTiger

```
class SiberianTiger extends Tiger{
public void setupSiberianTiger(int intensity,int level){
  pounce(intenisty);
  threatlevel(level);
}
```

}

```
public static void main(){
Attack attack =new SiberianTiger();
//setup the Siberian Tiger meow >.<
((SiberianTiger)attack).setupSiberianTiger(4,5);
}
```

So my question is it a good design decision to initialize the SiberianTiger instance the way I am doing. How can I improve upon it.
((SiberianTiger)attack).setupSiberianTiger(4,5);

Comment: Why would you create a subclass of `Tiger` and save it as an `Attack` type? Stick to objects and save your `SiberianTiger` as `Tiger`. Also think about creators. Using `public SiberianTiger(int density, int level)` saves you the need of casting your `Tiger` to any other subclass to initialize. So creators > initializers.

Comment: No, not good. I'd recommend you study the java collections interfaces and classes, Like `List` and `ArrayList`. To to understand how `List` exposes functionality that is broadly useful, while hiding the actual implementation

Answer (score 4):

You should declare your variables with the type you know you will use the fields and methods available. In this case, there's no benefit in declaring this:

```
Attack attack = new SiberianTiger();
((SiberianTiger)attack).setupSiberianTiger(4,5);
```

It is better to declare the variable as `SiberianTiger`:

```
SiberianTiger siberianTiger = new SiberianTiger();
siberianTiger.setupSiberianTiger(4,5);
```

The benefit of using super class or interface cannot be seen in this small piece of code. For instance, you can see it if you have a collection of `Attack`s:

```
List<Attack> attackList = new ArrayList<>();

SiberianTiger siberianTiger = new SiberianTiger();
siberianTiger.setupSiberianTiger(4,5);
attackList.add(siberianTiger);

for (Attack attack : attackList) {
    attack.<doSomething>();
}
```

Of course, there are other ways to improve this design like creating a proper constructor for `SiberianTiger` where you pass the variables, apply Factory Pattern or Builder, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a factory class and avoid the casting.

Clients should deal with `Attack` references, not concrete subtypes.

I agree with the comment about the interface name: good names matter.  I'd prefer `Attacker`.

```
public class AttackerFactory {
    private static final AttackerFactory instance = new AttackerFactory();

    private AttackerFactory() {}

    public static AttackerFactory getInstance() { return instance; }

    public Attack createAttacker(Class<Attack> attackerClass, int intensity, int threatLevel) {
        // Create what you want here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No.  A design that requires you to cast is not clean.  Fortunately for you, there's an easy alternative in this case:

```
public static void main(){
    SiberianTiger attack = new SiberianTiger();
    //setup the Siberian Tiger meow >.<
    attack.setupSiberianTiger(4,5);
}
```

More generally, you should always declare the least-specific type *that is consistent with your usage requirements*.  In your case, you want to use an initialization method that is specific to class `SiberianTiger`, so that's the type you should be declaring.

You can certainly pass that `SiberianTiger` object to a method that accepts any kind of `Attack`, or assign it to such a variable, etc..  That's an altogether different matter.